# MySQL cumulative sum depending on type

Tags: mysql, sql, sum, dashboard

Using MySQL I have this table:
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QwMLY.png)

What I'm trying to do is to cumulatively sum the column "montant" by date but if the row I'm adding has the Type CONTRIBUTION I keep it positive and if the row has the type WITHDRAW I make it negative.

So as a result I should get :

```
2021-03-10 10200 (100+2600-2500+10000)
2021-03-11 7700 (10200-2500)
```

I hope I made it clear what I'm trying to do.

I made this query which probably close:

select cast(date as date) as d, (select sum(montant) from jackpot where type='CONTRIBUTION' and cast(date as date) = d ) - (select sum(montant) from jackpot where type='WITHDRAW' and cast(date as date) = d ) as value from jackpot GROUP by cast(date as date);

but it's giving me this result

[image: 2]

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm . . . Use conditional aggregation to get the correct sum.  Use a cumulative sum window function to get the running sum:

```
select date(date),
       sum(case when type = 'CONTRIBUTION' then montant
                when type = 'WITHDRAW' then -montant
           end) as sum_on_date,
       sum(sum(case when type = 'CONTRIBUTION' then montant
                    when type = 'WITHDRAW' then -montant
               end)
          ) over (order by date(date)) as running_sum
from jackpot
group by date(date);
```